# Send placed orders to a custom email address

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am trying to send an email to a specific address (xxxxx@gmail.com) after every successful order placed. I intend to capture the signal that was fired and send the email based off those details. I forked the order app and this is from the order model

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.order.signals import order_placed
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from oscar.apps.checkout.signals import post_checkout
from oscar.apps.order.abstract_models import AbstractOrder

class Order(AbstractOrder):

    def send_order_request(sender, **kwargs):
        order = kwargs['instance']
        subject = 'New order placed'
        send_mail(subject, order, ['xxxxx@gmail.com'])

    order_placed.connect(send_order_request, order=self.order, 
     user=self.user)

from oscar.apps.order.models import *
```

Im currently getting an error that says self is not defined. Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: post the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use the self function, you must first add it when creating the method. As such:

```
def send_order_request(self, sender, **kwargs):
...
```

When creating a method, you can put in an optional argument called self.